# Get the name of opened file(through a batch file) associated through a batch file(Closed by owner)

Tags: batch-file

You may want to correct the title.. But I'll try to explain what I really want..

I have this in my batch file(**Assoc.bat**):

```
@echo off
Assoc .unity3d=unity3dfile
Ftype unity3dfile="%homedrive%\MyFolder\Player.bat" %1
```

And another one(**Player.bat**):

```
@echo off
echo %1
pause
```

What I want is **Player.bat** to detect the name of the **.unity3d** file that I opened.

*I'll make it shorter for you.:*

**Assoc.bat** associates the **.unity3d** file, so it will be opened by the **"Player.bat"** file in my custom folder..

**Player.bat** has to output the name of the **.unity3d** file that was opened(when I open the .unity3d file, it opens **Player.bat** file), so the output should look like this:

> "[path]\Game.unity3d"

And I know that "%1" gets the name of a file that was "Drag n' Dropped" on the batch file. But that's what I don't want.

**Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcAk441cDYA&feature=youtu.be)**

I hope you understood my English and what I want..
Please don't hate me for that..

***Any ideas?***

**Edit: I found out a different way to make my program that I'm woking on work.**

**Thank you all for you trying to hlep.**

Comment: ??? Have you tried your code? - You should see the full path when you `echo %1`

Comment: You didn't understand then...

Comment: I know that I can drag and drop the file on the batch file, but that's not what I want

Comment: And I wouldn't be even asking If I didn't

Comment: I'll upload a video or a pictre and you'll see.

Comment: I just ran the experiment myself and player.bat successfully ECHOed the full path to the .unity3d file. I did not "drag and drop". I am using Win 7.

Comment: me too.
I'm uploading a video, but I edited the path(because I need to have that path in there).
I would like to see how you did that/how it works for you.
You can make a video too.

Comment: ok, here is [the video](http://youtu.be/UcAk441cDYA)

Comment: Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Have patience - give people a chance to do research and provide a well thought out answer. Also, comments are not for rapid fire streams of quick thoughts - use chat for that. If you want to comment, try to collect your thoughts into a single comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh - I see the problem. The path to your .unity3d file includes a space, which corrupts the parsing of the file argument.

The simple fix is to include quotes around `%1` when you define FTYPE

```
ftype unity3dfile="%homedrive%\MyFolder\Player.bat" "%1"
```

Comment: Still the same problem. The output of the Player.bat is still the same(ECHO is off or whatever it says..).

Comment: @TomLenc - It worked for me when there was a space in the path. I cannot read the text in your video when it fails upon double click. Please edit your question and include the exact message you get when it fails. (It is easiest to read if you post it as code) Also, please provide an English translation of the message if you can.

Comment: When I drag and drop Game.unity3d on Player.bat, it shows the path.

The only problem is:
**When the Player.bat is the default "program" to open .unity3d files and when I double-click/open the Game.unity3d file, the output is empty.(that's why it was talking about ECHO is off..).**

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce the results in your video. I create the same files and folders, and everything works for me (after I add quotes around `%1` in ftype definition). I'm stumped.

Comment: Well if there's no way to do that, then if you know how to disAssociate a file?
I will need that.

Answer (score 0):

In your `assoc.bat` file you need to use

```
Ftype unity3dfile="%homedrive%\MyFolder\Player.bat" "%%1"
```

You need to escape the percent sign to prevent the parser to replace `%1` with the first argument to `assoc.bat`.